# Is there a way to flag user profile spam?

Tags: support

I stumbled over this the user profile on Drupal SE. It belongs to somebody whose nick is "[Taken 3 Online FREE Full HD](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/42542/taken-3-online-free-full-hd)".

This year old profile is clearly created just to promote an URL (I haven't clicked, since it may even link to malware), which has nothing to do with Drupal.

I know how to flag spam in Q&A, but can't find anything to flag a profile.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to flag user profiles. If the users didn't post anything, you can just open a question on this very site, so the moderators can take the necessary actions.

I deleted the account, since the user didn't want to participate in our site, and it was only created to post those links you saw in their user profile.